# Jar file when extracted and rebuilt, isn't working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, project, manifest

I'll try to be clear and concise on this.

i have a jar file of a project which is working perfectly. Now I need to make some changes to the application so i extracted that jar using this command.

```
  jar xf jwire.jar
```

the files extracted are

- META-INF (containing manifest file)
- Resources (containing pictures used in application)
- Jwire (containg classes and java files)
- .classpath
- .project
- manifest.mf (another manifest file with some other path to main class)

i also  added two empty folders src and bin here on somebodys suggestion.
now i'm trying to create the jar file again using all these folders.
 Without making any type of changes I'm trying to rebuild this jar using the following

```
      jar cf newjar.jar G:\Project1\project
```

**NOTE:- I am guessing it's the right way to build the file. Please point if it's not right.**

G:\Project1\project is the path to above mentioned files and folders.
The jar created using this is of size 729kb while the earlier one had 711Kb and when I run it using the following command.

```
     java -jar newjwire.jar
```

I get the following message

```
        no main manifest attribute, in newjwire.jar
```

Next i tried extracting this newjwire.jar file in order to see its manifest file. I got this folder META-INF containing the MANIFEST.MF file. it didn't have the path to the main class , So I edited it and put the modified file back on using the following command

```
        jar uf newjwire.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

when I run this jar, I get the following message

```
              Error: Ivalid or corrupt jarfile newjwire.jar
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I building the jar file the right way? I used eclipse juno too and it gave the same message to that mainclass is missing. There is a main class consisting the main function. Is this something has to do with My orignal jar having two MANIFEST file.

I hope the problem is understandable. Clear and detailed answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Try and list the rebuilt jar contents using `jar tf your.jar`; are the contents the one you expect?

Comment: open it with a zip browser and check its tree structure

Answer (score 1):

you're supposed to update JAR files by `jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`

see this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: @DavidWallace she extracts, adds two folders and packs it back, without using `jar uf`

Comment: @mangusta i extracted the MANIFEST file and edited it. Then i used jar uf newjwire.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.M  to put it back in my newjwire.jar. Next thing , it becomes invalid file

Comment: @user1613603 was there a difference between manifest of your jar BEFORE you rebuilt it, and AFTER? try building with `jar cfm` and include the old manifest of your jar (the original one)

Comment: @mangusta I am doing exactly the same but somehow the manifest get changes again and the manifest file is still empty. When i updated the new jar using  "jar uf " command , the jar became invalid.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) you need to EITHER have `Manifest.txt` present when you create or update the JAR, or use the `e` option to specify the main class.  Probably the latter would make more sense in your case.

```
jar cfe newjar.jar mypackage.MainClass G:\Project1\project
```

Comment: I did what you said. "jar cfe newjar.jar jwire.f G:\Project1\project".                                                    When I ran it , i got this message "Error : Couldn't find or load main class jwire.f".

Comment: So does the file `jwire/f.class` exist?

Comment: @user1613603 :) you're supposed to specify a full package path to your `f` class. seems `f` is somewhere else

Comment: @david Yes it does. But I have to notify you here that the orignal workable jar consisted of two manifest files. One was inside META-INF which has "mainclass: jwire.f" while there's another manifest.mf file that has this line "mainclass: furi.f" . When i checked the code of the files inside jwire including file 'f', they all import JWIRE package. but when i import this project on eclipse , the package shown is furi. It's quite confusing.

Comment: I'm having real trouble following all those details.  Why are there two manifest files?  It's probably not relevant anyway - only the one inside `META-INF` should make any difference.  So the main class file is `G:\Project1\project\jwire\f.class`, and the source file for it has `package jwire` at the top, and is called `f.java`, right?

Comment: @DavidWallace   Yes , You are right . And also it's compiled so there's f.class. That jar is working fine. But the new jar isn't working at all. The manifest file keeps changing.

Comment: Then I'm very sorry, I'm right out of answers.  If your set-up is exactly as you described, then `jar cfe newjar.jar jwire.f G:\Project1\project` is the correct command.  I can't imagine why it is giving you the error that you claim.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Did you try it by creating a `Manifest.txt`, as described on the page that I linked to?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes i did. I'll try again from start .nevermind you tried. Thanks

Comment: Did this work for you in the end?  If it didn't, then you shouldn't accept my answer, as it will discourage someone else from coming along and answering; and it's quite likely that someone in the Stack Overflow community can give you a better and more helpful answer than I could.  I won't be offended if you un-accept - the green tick is only for answers that give you what you needed.